# Android studio keeps underlining all classes red while saying that R doesn't exist

Tags: android-studio

I know this has been asked many times, but usually the advice is something along the lines of "decrease Android gradle plugins version" or something like that. Firstly, that doesn't seem to work for me, secondly, decreasing the version in order to solve this kind of problem doesn't seem like a good practice and I'd like to avoid it (especially since Android Studio warns me I should increase the version back again when I try to decrease it).

So now what exactly is happening + some details that might help:

- Every class is underlined with red color in the project explorer and there are loads of "java package R does not exist" messages in the Problems view
- When I open any class, suddenly its red underline disappears and there are actually no errors in this class
- It happens if and only if AS does an automatic build (I can see "21:03 Auto build completed with errors" in the Event log). When I build manually, there are no errors in the Problems view, and no class is underlined (that is, until AS does auto build again, which happens all the time)
- In any way, this doesn't prevent building of the application/APK/AAB, installing it on the phone/virtual, and running it
- This has been happening ever since I updated Android Studio to v4.1 (I now use Android gradle plugin v4.1.0)

(Of course, I also tried all the obvious stuff - deleting every temporary/generated file, invalidating cache, restarting, cleaning, etc. etc. Everything I could think of.)

Answer (score -1):

I had a problem like this before, it had nothing to do with the gradle ijust add "**import com.package.appname.R;**" into myclass and is worked

Comment: Obviously, I have that in every class already (otherwise I wouldn't be able to reference R in the code)